# postgres SQL Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have an SQL query that works through a Grafana dashboard is this possible to recreate in Pandas?

In Grafana:

```
SELECT
  "time" AS "time",
  metric AS metric,
  value
FROM volttron
WHERE
  $__timeFilter("time") AND
  kv_tags->'equip_name' = '["35201"]' AND
  'power' = any(m_tags)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Trying to recreate in Pandas postgress connection with `psycopg2`:

```
eGauge35201 = pd.read_sql('SELECT "time" AS "time", metric AS metric, value FROM volttron WHERE $__timeFilter("time") AND kv_tags->equip_name = ["35201"] AND power = any(m_tags) ORDER BY 1,2', dbconn)
```

This throws a lot of errors:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT "time" AS "time", metric AS metric, value FROM volttron WHERE $__timeFilter("time") AND kv_tags->equip_name = ["35201"] AND power = any(m_tags) ORDER BY 1,2': syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: ...c AS metric, value FROM slipstream_volttron WHERE $__timeFil...
```

Im trying to build a dataframe directly... Sorry still learning db any tips greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Not using Grafana, I'm pretty sure that `$__timeFilter` and `m_tags` is something that should come from Grafana's end, and is then replaced by proper PostgreSQL expressions when when the query is actually made to the database after you defined it.

The query also uses several protected SQL words like "time" which is correctly escaped, and value, which isn't. This can lead to some unwanted behaviour.

I would recreate this query for Pandas to understand properly. But without knowing what e.g. `$__timeFilter` is replaced with, we cannot know what it should be. You could e.g. monitor Grafana's or the database's logs.

From a quick Google search, [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/inspect-panel/#view-raw-request-and-response-to-data-source) looks promising.